# When I run a .MPX FILE ,I getting a message "An import error occurred"

Tags: ms-project

When I run a `.MPX` file ,I am getting this pop up message. Plese help me to tell what to do to run this file [image: message]

Comment: consider adding more information in your question

Comment: mainly wrong formatting corrected showing image

Answer (score 0):

The MPX file type is a legacy text-based file format which can be used by older versions of Microsoft Project. The `.mpx` extension is associated with Microsoft Project, which is why Project is being used to open the file in the screenshot you provided. It may be that the file is corrupt or is not actually an MS Project MPX file, which is why Project is having problems opening it. If this is still an issue, posting a sample file will help provide a more specific diagnosis of the error message.